# Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net, oledb, oledbdatareader

```
 myConnection.Open()
    rtb_Address.Clear()
    txt_Name.Clear()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (cus_ID = '" & txt_ID.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
        rtb_Address.Text = dr("cus_Addr").ToString
        txt_Name.Text = dr("cus_Name").ToString
    End While
    myConnection.Close()
```

Error in dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

dr is declared as OleDbDataReader

Comment: "Data type mismatch.." is a catch all error - read SQL Syntax error. Possible that cus_ID is numeric and the comparison text is not numeric. Some back ends tolerate quoted numeric text - if youse doesn't just don't insert the quote marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cus_ID` is probaly a numeric data type, but you try to query it with a string: `(cus_ID = 'thevalue')`.

Just remove the enclosing `'`: `(cus_ID = thevalue)`

or better, use a parameterized query to prevent sql-injection.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the following:

```
 Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE cus_ID = @ID", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txt_ID.Text)

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While dr.Read()
      rtb_Address.Text = dr("cus_Addr").ToString
      txt_Name.Text = dr("cus_Name").ToString
    End While

 End Using
```

Comment: The error is: `Data type mismatch in criteria expression`, as the title says.

Comment: My bad, then as @大师燈XiHuan and I mentioned, the probable cause is the ' around the ID, although it would help if we knew what data type cus_ID is (string, guid / uniqueidentifier, integer etc)

Comment: Why did my answer get a -1?

Comment: Don't know. Wasn't me.